# customizing our search bar

Tags: jquery, css, search

If you check out google, they have some excellent features on their search bar, but I wondered if anyone could point me in the direction to replicate some of these features ?

Example:
[image]

We would like to add the X at the end of the search box in the input field, float right.
Not sure though how this is done, I presume the css is straightfoward, but not sure on the scripting to do this without refreshing the page.

Any ideas please.

Our search box is auto suggest, code isnt really necessary ( html ) to display here, but can post if people need to see our simple code. Moreover wondered if anyone had actually added a clear results X within the input field similar to that image....

Or post some links please.. bugger it here is our html.

```
<input name="suburbs" id="suburbs" type="text" placeholder="eg: Apples" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" autocomplete="off" /></input>
                            <!--added autosuggest-->
                                <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!--//auto suggest end-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source of the Google page using for example firebug, you will see that the `x` is not part of the input field, it's an `x` wrapped in a link tag in the next table column (the input is put in the previous column along with some other stuff).

Just add some javascript to the link tag to clear the input and cancel it's standard action and you have the whole effect.

Comment: yeah had looked at their code, wasnt sure how they did it. Also < no JS expert so that part is out for me lol. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#searchBar span').click(function () {
                $('#searchBar input[type=text]').val('');
            });

        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        input[type=text]
        {
            border:solid 1px #ccc;
            width:400px;
            padding:5px;
            padding-right:25px;
            }

         #searchBar span 
         {
             margin-left:-25px;
             margin-right:10px;
             font-family:Arial;
             color:blue;
             cursor:pointer;
             zoom:1;
             }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchBar">
        <input type="text" />
        <span title="Clear search">X</span>
        <input type="button" value="search" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/4UAR7/ Not sure what your script does ? could you explain .

Comment: It's a simple jQuery code. it adds a click event handler to the X, so when you click on the X it cleans the value of the text box. if you don't want to use jQuery you can achieve the same thing using document.getElementById('TextBoxID').value = '';

Comment: the x is simply in a span tag after the input text box...it just has negative margin so it will appear as it was on the text input

Comment: thanks but now I am even more baffled, lol. Thanks for your help. Will have to look elsewhere to minimise your time wasting with this idiot

Comment: @422 If you're not comfortable with the negative margin, you can just leave the `X` where it is, put a border around the `@searchBar` element and remove the border from the input. That's what Google is doing, the `X` appears to be part of the input, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function() {
    // if text input field value is not empty show the "X" button
    $("#field").keyup(function() {
        $("#x").fadeIn();
        if ($.trim($("#field").val()) == "") {
            $("#x").fadeOut();
        }
    });
    // on click of "X", delete input field value and hide "X"
    $("#x").click(function() {
        $("#field").val("");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9evU/1/)